# Bessel-Gaussian beams

Tags: electromagnetism, optics

I want to know what are Bessel-Gaussian beams, how do they creat and what do they use for.
Is there any article about them?
How can I calculate it from Helmholtz equation in spherical coordinate?

Comment: One place to start is [the Edmund Optics website](https://www.edmundoptics.com/knowledge-center/application-notes/lasers/an-in-depth-look-at-axicons/).  Another is [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axicon)